# "Парк Героев-Пожарных". Слово "пожарных" с прописной или со строчной?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Как бы вы написали следующее название (условное): **парк Героев-П(п)пожарных**?
Второе слово с прописной или со строчной?

В правилах ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Второе слово с прописной или со строчной?

Я бы написал с прописной  — по аналогии с ***улицей Героев-Панфиловцев***

(такое её написание фиксируется словарём Лопатина, Нечаевой и Чельцовой "Прописная или строчная", М.,2007).

Answer (score 1):

парк Героев-пожарных:

герои-пожарные - нарицательное сложное слово (составное наименование), в названии "парк Героев-пожарных" пишется с прописной буквы (также является словом особой важности).

Ответ исправлен.

Comment: Что значит особой важности?

Comment: У Лопатина это слова, выражающие высокие священные понятия (Родина, Отчизна и т.д.)

Comment: А почему вдруг название улицы - не имя собственное? Это тоже у Лопатина? ))) Улица Строителей? Вы, наверное не очень четко вырожились. ***Вторая часть*** - не имя собственное. Да?

Comment: Совсем не четко. Я хотела сказать, что вторая часть в дефисных названиях пишется с прописной буквы не часто - обычно в именах и географических названиях, где оба  слова участвуют в составлении названия.

Answer (score 1):

> В Петербурге начинается строительство парка Героев-Пожарных
> ([Официальный сайт Администрации Санкт-Петербурга)](https://www.gov.spb.ru/)

- 

> В составных названиях с прописной буквы пишутся все слова, кроме служебных слов и родовых наименований ([§ 17. Географические и административно-территориальные названия](http://rosental-book.ru/ortho_iii.html#sect17))

Comment: rosental-book.ru/ortho_iii.html#sect17 - нормальная ссылка.  Зачем заменять её на архивную копию с сомнительного архива - непонятно.